# Missing values issue

Tags: r, missing-data, imputation

I have a dataset (data1.csv) that contains some missing data (missing at random), I am creating a subset from this dataset (d1) such that only complete observations are retained in d2. I am using the **ftable** ,  **as.data.frame** function and creating a column **p** that represent the percentage of each combination.

```
 d1 = read.csv("C:/Users/....../Data1.csv",header=T)

   y x1 x2 x3
1  1  2  1 NA
2  0  2 NA  0
3  1 NA  1  1
4  0  3  1  0
5  0  2  0 NA
6  0  1  0  1
7  1 NA NA  1
8  1  3  0  1
9  1  2  0  0
10 0  3  0 NA
11 1 NA  0  1
12 1  3 NA  1
13 0  3  1 NA
14 0 NA  1  0
15 1  1  0 NA
16 0  1 NA  1
17 1 NA  0 NA
18 0  3  1  1
19 0  1 NA  0
20 0 NA  0  1

 d2= d1[complete.cases(d1),]
 d2

   y x1 x2 x3
4  0  3  1  0
6  0  1  0  1
8  1  3  0  1
9  1  2  0  0
18 0  3  1  1


 d3= ftable(d2)
 d4=as.data.frame(d3)
 d4


 y x1 x2 x3 Freq   p
 1  0  1  0  0    0 0.0
 2  1  1  0  0    0 0.0
 3  0  2  0  0    0 0.0
 4  1  2  0  0    1 0.2
 5  0  3  0  0    0 0.0
 6  1  3  0  0    0 0.0
 7  0  1  1  0    0 0.0
 8  1  1  1  0    0 0.0
 9  0  2  1  0    0 0.0
 10 1  2  1  0    0 0.0
 11 0  3  1  0    1 0.2
 12 1  3  1  0    0 0.0
 13 0  1  0  1    1 0.2
 14 1  1  0  1    0 0.0
 15 0  2  0  1    0 0.0
 16 1  2  0  1    0 0.0
 17 0  3  0  1    0 0.0
 18 1  3  0  1    1 0.2
 19 0  1  1  1    0 0.0
 20 1  1  1  1    0 0.0
 21 0  2  1  1    0 0.0
 22 1  2  1  1    0 0.0
 23 0  3  1  1    1 0.2
 24 1  3  1  1    0 0.0
```

The function **ftable** ,  **as.data.frame** works fine but the problem is I still see ALL these observations in the results (d4) which dosent make sense. I thought I got rid of this when i did complete.cases(d1)

So need help getting rid of missing values and doing frequency table only for these complete observations

```
   y x1 x2 x3
4  0  3  1  0
6  0  1  0  1
8  1  3  0  1
9  1  2  0  0
18 0  3  1  1
```

Comment: Are the issing values perhaps called '. ' (trailing space) or some other syntactic horror? btw you can also hand in an array of possible missing value symbols to `read.csv` with the `na.strings` parameter.

Comment: Please provide a small example of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This you sample input data

```
d1<-structure(list(y = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), x1 = c(2L, 2L, NA, 3L, 
2L, 1L, NA, 3L, 2L, 3L, NA, 3L, 3L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 3L, 1L, NA
), x2 = c(1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 1L, 
1L, 0L, NA, 0L, 1L, NA, 0L), x3 = c(NA, 0L, 1L, 0L, NA, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 0L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 0L, 1L)), .Names = c("y", 
"x1", "x2", "x3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", 
"15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"))
```

These commands

```
d2 <- d1[complete.cases(d1),]
d3 <- ftable(d2)
d4 <- as.data.frame(d3)
d4
```

return the folowing table.

```
   y x1 x2 x3 Freq
1  0  1  0  0    0
2  1  1  0  0    0
3  0  2  0  0    0
4  1  2  0  0    1
5  0  3  0  0    0
6  1  3  0  0    0
7  0  1  1  0    0
8  1  1  1  0    0
9  0  2  1  0    0
10 1  2  1  0    0
11 0  3  1  0    1
12 1  3  1  0    0
13 0  1  0  1    1
14 1  1  0  1    0
15 0  2  0  1    0
16 1  2  0  1    0
17 0  3  0  1    0
18 1  3  0  1    1
19 0  1  1  1    0
20 1  1  1  1    0
21 0  2  1  1    0
22 1  2  1  1    0
23 0  3  1  1    1
24 1  3  1  1    0
```

There aren't exactly the original rows. These are all the possible combinations of `y`, `x1`, `x2`, and `x3` in your complete cases. If you only want those that actually had observations, you could do

```
 subset(d4, Freq>0)
```

but this basically gets you back to `d2`

```
4  1  2  0  0    1
11 0  3  1  0    1
13 0  1  0  1    1
18 1  3  0  1    1
23 0  3  1  1    1
```

It seems unclear what you expected `ftable` to do or how you expected the result to be different than `d2` or where your `p` column came from. The code is working exactly as I expect so I'm not sure what you thought the result would be.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Flick, looks like I did not think through this, i was expecting the ftable and as.data.frame function to take only the 4 complete observations since i had filtered there already...anyway this is clear now....Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Look up ?complete.cases(). It will do what you're looking for; you can specify missing value and what columns you want to do it for.